# Minimum characters for a comment

Tags: bug, comments

When writing a comment there is this nifty little text to help you past the minimum requirements of comment length:

> enter at least 15 characters

which changes into

> 13 more to go...

as you type.

When I wanted to comment something small I noticed that I reached:

> 1 more to go...

So I randomly added another space, after which the text changed into:

> 585 characters left

So I decided to hit the post button which showed me the following error:

[image: error message]

So how can we make it clear that spaces don't count toward the 15 character requirement, and accordingly avoid the inconsistency between the messages, as this triggers my OCD quite hard ;)

Comment: just dont be OCD! hehe, or have the code trim() whats in the textbox before doing a character length check